# creating policy with aws .net sdk

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

using .net sdk I am trying to create a policy call the Amazon.IdentityManagement.AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient.CreatePolicy method.

it creates an exception with the following information

"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

The security token included in the request is invalid."

I've updated the policy for the user whose aws credentials the app uses but nothing seems to work.  I feel like I'm missing something obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your application actually accessing your AWS credentials before making the call? try putting them inline in your code even though that's discouraged just as a test. If it works correctly, something is wrong with accessing your creds file.

Comment: thanks.  it was a simple mistake on my part.  I had mucked up something creating the credentials